# trouble with accessing a class from a different class

Tags: c++, class, oop

just started to learn c++.I'm trying new things in c++ on thing i wanted to try is to access a class from another class and change its instances and print its instance on screen.

I would like to know 2 things 1)whats wrong with my code 2)where should i declare class declarations (in main file or class definition file?)

here is the error log -

```
'object::carrier' uses undefined class 'sub'
 'cout': is not a member of 'std'
 'cout': undeclared identifier
```

this is what i came up with-
**source.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "stuff.h"

int main()
{
    object spoon(3);
    spoon.get();

}
```

**stuff.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class object;
class sub;


class object
{
private:
    std::vector <sub> thing;
public:
    object(int n);
    void get() const;
};


class sub
{
private:
    int num;
public:
    void set_num(int n);

};
```

**stuff.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include "stuff.h"

// methods for object
object::object(int n)
{
    sub carrier;
    carrier.set_num(n);
}

void object::get() const
{
    std::cout << carrier.num;
}

// methods for sub




void sub::set_num(int temp_num)
{
    num = temp_num;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you believe that there might be something wrong with the shown code?

Comment: It seems you are trying to access `sub carrier;` in your `get` - however `carrier` is a local variable in the constructor, it doesn't exist outside of that function. Also `carrier.num` is trying to access a `private` member, that also cannot work

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You have two files you are calling `stuff.cpp`, that's confusing. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Yksisarvinen sry forgot to add errors, now ive added the log

Comment: @pcarter i define my methods in .h file and then define the methods in .cpp file.Both files are generated by visual studio

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i'm now to oop so i need your help finding what went wrong.Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that your first `stuff.cpp` should really be labelled `stuff.h` in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

In your `object` class, specifically `object::get` definitions, you use the variable `carrier` without it being in scope.

When you declare the variable `sub carrier` in your constructor, it is only accessible in the same scope, that is, inside the constructor. Once your program leaves the scope, the variable `carrier` is deallocated (deleted).

You must add the variable `sub carrier` as a member to your class like so:

```cpp
class object
{
private:
  sub carrier

  // other stuff
}
```

**Edit**:
I so you edited your question.

You must either replace `cout` with `std::cout` because `cout` is part of the c++ standard library. Alternatively, a less verbose option would be to add `using namespace std;` at the top of every `.cpp` file. This basically tells the compiler that you can use the namespace `std` without explicitly saying it. But don't do it for `.h` files. It's not a good idea.

Comment: yes i forgot to add `std::` now i changed it.But still im getting errors even after i add `sub carrier` in my class `object`. Here are the errors -
`'object::carrier' uses undefined class 'sub' `, `'cout': is not a member of 'std'``,``'cout': undeclared identifier`.Thanks

Comment: You must put the declaration of `class sub` before `class object` so that `class object` can access it. It is generally a *very* bad idea to use `using namespace ...` in a header file so just replace `cout` with `std::cout` in your `.h` file.